# python gstreamer script error message no element "h264parse"

Tags: python, ubuntu, gstreamer

I am running a Python script in Ubuntu. The script uses gstreamer.  I get the following error message.

error: no element "h264parse"

Let me know if any other information would be helpful.

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h264parse is part of the "gst-plugins-bad" , you will want to install them through your package manager, if your script imports Gst from gi.repository you will want the 1.0 plugins, the 0.10 otherwise.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, I'm new to Unbuntu and Python so I'm not sure how to install gst-plugins-bad.  I tried sudo apt-get install gst-plugins-bad and I also tried adding python-pip to the end of the same command line.  Or, do I download the zip file from git and then what it the command for installing from the downloaded files/folder?

Comment: apt-cache search gst-plugins-bad should show you available packages. You can then apt-get install the relevant one.

Comment: apt-cache search gst-plugins-bad

just returns to the command prompt without any information

Comment: ok, I figured that out, I think I got gst-plugins-bad installed but now I am getting the error message:  no element ffdec_h264

Comment: part of gst-plugins-ffmpeg (now called gst-libav)