# GLib.Error: gst_parse_error: no element "zbar"

Tags: python, gstreamer, archlinux, python-gstreamer

```
from gi.repository import GdkX11, GstVideo

p = 'v4l2src ! tee name=t ! queue ! videoconvert ! zbar ! fakesink t. ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink'
self.a = a = Gst.parse_launch(p)
```

Error:

```
    self.a = a = Gst.parse_launch(p)
GLib.Error: gst_parse_error: no element "zbar" (1)
```

Following the answer to [python gstreamer script error message no element "h264parse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757936/python-gstreamer-script-error-message-no-element-h264parse), I found [`zbar` is a part of `gst-plugins-bad`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html), but I've already installed `gst-plugins-bad  1.4.5-1`. So why am I still getting this error?

I'm using Arch Linux, if it helps.

Comment: Is it error from the c layer? Do you need to install the zbar package from pacman or aur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/43696) in [`gst-plugins-bad` Arch package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gst-plugins-bad/). Just add `zbar` to `depends` in [`PKGBUILD`](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/gst-plugins-bad), [build](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Build_the_package) it and [install](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Install_the_package).