# gi.repository.GLib.Error: gst_parse_error: no element "rsvgoverlay" (1)

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer, pygobject, gobject

I get the following error:
`gi.repository.GLib.Error: gst_parse_error: no element "rsvgoverlay" (1)`

for the following line of code:
`PIPELINE += """ ! {leaky_q} ! {videoflip} ! videoconvert ! rsvgoverlay name=overlay ! videoconvert """`

`appsrc_pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(appsrc_pipeline)`

This is running on a virtual environment on a raspberry pi4. The same code works perfectly on another raspberry pi4 with no virtual environment. I am using python3.7.

Can someone please tell me what is going on?

I could only find this link which was slightly relevant but could not understand it: [GLib.Error: gst_parse_error: no element "zbar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865536/glib-error-gst-parse-error-no-element-zbar)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`rsvgoverlay` is one of many elements that can be installed. It seems it is missing on your installation. This particular one is part of the `gst-plugins-bad` package. So check your package manager if you find a package that sounds similar. The `-bad` packge may not be installed by default since it contains "bad" plugins. They are not bad per-se, there are not just well maintained and may or not work as expected.